Best way to fix hole in engineered wood flooring
So I have some termite damage in my engineered wood flooring which resulted in a small hole. I was wondering if I could fill it up and paint over it and the best way to go about this. Replacing the plank is really the last option. Any tips or ideas?



Yea I think it’s engineered wood actually thanks for the correction.

The other answer would be to cut out and replace the entire damaged piece. Or just put a piece of furniture over it...

Filling will make the dent much more conspicuous. Unless you meticulously match color, grain, and texture it'll be ugly. I see two avenues:

Gently pry up the top layer. Fill the void with filler or epoxy. Let it set with the top layer held flat. Rub it with nail hole filler of the same color to conceal remaining edges.

Fill the void as it is with clear epoxy. It may allow enough color through to  somewhat conceal itself.



is there an epoxy you would suggest I use?

Yes, allow the epoxy to harden a little bit before you press the recovered pieces of "wood" into it.  Press them in with a board or something so thet're flush with the board.
